# URLrewriting in asp.net 3.5 with example

Tags: asp.net

can anyone please provide me the details how we can implement custom URL rewriting in asp.net

My current url is look like below :

www.domainname.com/News/default.aspx?newstitle=todays latest news
And now I would like to redirect to below url :

www.domainname.com/News/todays-latest-news

Please suggest me how we can achieve the same using asp.net 3.5 version.

Answer (score 2):

Use Routing... :

[ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX)

[How to: Use Routing with Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Routing with ASP.NET Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx)

;)